# scrapy - get cookies from response/request headers

Tags: python, session, cookies, scrapy

I am trying to get the cookies from the request using this line of code  but got `[]` empty result

```
response.headers.getList('Set-Cookie')
```

and this

```
response.request.headers.get('Cookie')
```

when I `open_in_browser` the response I inspect the Network tab and see the cookies exist (See image below)

[image]

[image]

Any Idea? Thank you

Answer (score 4):

`response.headers.getlist("Set-Cookie")` works for me (Scrapy 1.4.0)

But first, check in shell if you actually have received this cookie:

```
scrapy shell
fetch('your_url')
response.headers.getlist("Set-Cookie")
```

Comment: I checked in shell, its empty `[]`, but when I do view response, I successfully logged in.

Comment: Set `COOKIES_DEBUG = True` in your settings file to see if you receive any cookies

Comment: I cant see any debug information related to cookies when i run the crawl.

Comment: That's why you don't see cookies in your output. Probably, cookies have been sent by some JavaScript. In this case you should use Selenium

Comment: Ill give it a try, i also try setting the user agent to mozilla, but no luck.